# How to save password of Gmail?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, gmail, aes

In one of my open source applications, I have to work with Gmail [Atom feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29).

Right now, I am using [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) to encrypt the Gmail password and store it. (The key is the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of the system along with some hard-coded string.)

The security is highly compromised here. If anyone has access to the machine (thus the MAC address) and my source code (it's open source), then he/she can get the Gmail password.

Thus, I strongly suggest users to create a new Gmail account, only for this software's purpose.

Is there a better mean of storing the password?

---

I agree with all of you that it's not a very good idea to store the password.

Actually my application will monitor the Gmail account for mails over a period of time, so if I don't save the password then I'll have to ask the user to enter the password every time the program starts. The idea of the application is that the user has to enter the password once and my application will notify about all new mails. The application will also, with the user's consent start with windows.

So, I have to store the password.

Is there a way?

(I am using [Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_Basic_Express).)

Comment: Don't store the users password?  If you require the user to be logged in, prompt for the password and send it over a secure connection but do not store.  Can't you allow google to handle the authentication?

Comment: @Pete: Google supports OAuth: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/

Comment: @Blender Sounds like a good answer to me ;)

Comment: Agree with @Pete -- DON'T store users' passwords. Ever! Suggest a dedicated account all you want, but do you *honestly* think anybody's going to do that? More to the point, I'll bet if you get a thousand users, at least ten of them will use the same username/password combination at Chase, WellsFargo or Citibank. Then if your database gets compromised, you've got enormous legal exposure!

Comment: @BobKaufman: Totally agree with you there.

Comment: I agree with all of you that its not a very good idea to store the password.

actually my app will monitor the gmail account for mails over a period of time, so if I don't save the password the I'll have to ask the user to enter the password every time the program starts. the idea of the app is that the user has to enter the password once and my app will notify about all new mails. the app will also, with the user's consent start with windows.

so, I have to store the password.

kindly suggest a way.

Comment: @max_force -- I've been asked to work on a couple of applications where users would have to share not only gmail passwords, but credentials to financial accounts as well. I've walked away from them and am glad I did. In each case, the application's marketing effort failed because for some reason, people are apprehensive about trusting a complete stranger with this information.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need to store personal information in a Windows application, try the [Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) - it encrypts your data using a key that is bound to the user account and / or its password.